# How to check code coverage by highlighting lines react app using visual studio code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, code-coverage, jestjs

Is there any way to highlight all lines which has code coverage for react app. I am using Jest. my editor is visual studio code.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [vscode-jest](https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest) plugin, it has codeLens (enabled by default).

Beware though, it's a little slow sometimes (on the first run especially). I disable 'run all on first load' option, to avoid that. The code coverage shown might be a little off sometimes due to these perf issues. But it works good enough for me most times. At the top of the file, it even shows the % of branches and line covered.

See related issue: https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/issues/181

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Id recommend using [Coverage Gutters](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryanluker.vscode-coverage-gutters).

Have yet to run into any issues with it. Even better its framework agnostic, handy if you're not just a JS dev.

[image]